# Don't get input and output value as double type in C

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double a,b;
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    printf("%lf\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting output `0.000000` — why? — but the same code gets input and output as `double` in a C program. With `float` type, the code works in C++. I have used GNU `gcc` compiler.

Comment: `%lf` is for `long double` isn't it?

Comment: Tagged [c], but the title says [c++].

Comment: what are you typing in when you run the program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  More urgently, please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Your code is nicely minimal and complete; that's good.  It isn't verifiable since you've not told us what the input is.  For many inputs, such as `0` or `0.0`, the output is perfectly legitimate.  What string are you typing?  Why don't you check that `scanf()` returns `1` to indicate that it successfully read one value?

Comment: @shivazi have you tried checking the return value of `scanf`? You can check any of the online man pages to see how you should be using it e.g. [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). If it doesnt return 1 then it hasnt parsed your value!!

Comment: Seems to work for me. https://ideone.com/8Pb4fl

Comment: Are you saying that your code works in C with both `double` and `float`, and it works in C++ with `float`, but it fails in C++ with `double`?  Are you changing the format string for `scanf()` as you switch between `float` and `double`?  Do you realize why you don't need to switch the `printf()` format in C?  Are you sure your C++ library recognizes `%lf` as a synonym for `%f`, expecting a `double` (or `float` automatically promoted to `double`)?  Which version of GCC (and G++) are you using, and on which platform?

Comment: What version of gcc did you use to compile the code?

Comment: Release 13.12  rev 9501 (2013/12/25 19:25:45)   gcc 4.7.1 Windows/unicode - 32 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) `%lf` is not existing per say.
In [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) it does.
(see `specifiers x length` table)

Lots of OS accept `%lf` in printf to be consistent, but Windows is not one of them.

So you have to scanf `%lf`, but printf `%f`, and it should work everywhere.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but … C99 and C11 both say for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html): _`l` (ell) Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long int` or `unsigned long int` argument; …; or has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion
specifier._  However, you note that Windows runtime library does not support `%lf` as a `printf()` format specification — which is perfectly plausible since it mostly adheres to C90 and not the later standards.

Comment: well yes, it should have no effect, but it does on mingw, thanks for the valuable addition